# Design View Not Working in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, contentplaceholder

I've been creating a new webforms website in c# and been working exclusively in source view until yesterday when I wanted to create a method for a button click for the only dynamic part of the site and I was confronted with this:

[image: no design view]

I've never seen this before! Every page is the same and it reoccurs on another machine with VS 2013 The site renders fine and publishes without issue. Other websites work fine, so it's got to be this project.

I don't know if this is a separate issue or is part of the same problem, but I managed to link up the button to a method using Resharper, but data from textboxes are not passing to the method, which again I've never had before.

It's a 30 page bootstrap site (replacing an old site) that I've nearly finished! Am I screwed??

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

It's not that I'm worried about seeing the page render in design view. I never use it. I just want to be able create the button click event method. At the moment the button click is just reloading the page and not passing form data to the method.

Comment: Why do you care about the design if your website is correctly rendered without any error. I have never seen a developer using the built-in designer for web projects. Please show use your source code if you absolutely want to make the designer happy. Try to disable R#

Comment: No I don't usually use design view at all it never renders properly anyway. I just want to create the method from the button click (double clicking on the button).

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to improper termination of the Visual Studio processes due to which the files get corrupted for which you might need to use system restore or re-installation of the product. Still assuming that its caused due to some setting mismatch we can perform the following steps.

```
1.right click on an html file listed in Solution Explorer
2.in dialog box that opens click on: Open With...
3.click on: HTML (Web Forms) Editor,  AND on the right pane click on Set it As Default
```

after this action all html files that you open have options: Design...Split...Source.

Reference : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/25d6c666-6216-4fa8-992b-f9bb088dfc7d/visual-studio-2013-missing-design-source-and-split-buttons